# Cannot get Docker to work with headless-wp-starter

Tags: linux, docker, wordpress, ubuntu-18.10

I'm posting this question here in the hope that I'm just using Docker wrong and someone can explain how to fix it. I don't think the problem is with the [headless-wp-starter](https://github.com/postlight/headless-wp-starter) GitHub project itself, but in case it is I will ask about it somewhere else.

Currently I'm trying to install this to develop locally on Ubuntu 18.10. Here's my installation process. I made sure to delete volumes/images/containers, etc. from my last Docker installation and start from scratch.

1. I'm trying to install headless-wp-starter, start by installing `docker` and `composer`

   ```
   sudo apt install composer docker`
   ```
2. Installing docker-compose separately as explained in the Docker Docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose).
3. Testing docker-compose to see if everything works.

   ```
   docker-compose --version  
   docker-compose version 1.24.0, build 0aa59064
   ```
4. Move contents of git into a whole new folder located at `/opt/lampp/htdocs/headless-wp`.

   ```
   cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/headless-wp  
   sudo docker-compose up -d
   ```

   I need sudo because I get:

   ```
   ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

   If it's at a nonstandard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
   ```
5. Everything works fine until the end where I get:

   ```
   Creating db-headless      ... done
   Creating frontend-graphql ... done
   Creating frontend         ... done
   Creating wp-headless      ... error

   ERROR: for wp-headless      
   Cannot start service wp-headless: OCI runtime create failed:   
   container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "chdir to cwd (\"/var/www/html\") set in config.json failed: 
   permission denied": unknown   
   ERROR: for wp-headless      
   Cannot start service wp-headless: OCI runtime create failed:    
   container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "chdir to cwd (\"/var/www/html\") set in config.json failed: permission denied": unknown      
   ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
   ```

I'm not familiar with Docker at all. I've googled this, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

I've been able to get wp-headless to run by changing this part of 
`docker-compose.yml`:

```
wp-headless:
    build: .
    command: bash -c 'install_wordpress && apache2-foreground'
    container_name: wp-headless
    depends_on:
        - db-headless
    env_file: ./.env
    ports:
        - '8080:8080'
    user: www-data
    volumes:
        - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
        - ./docker/install_wordpress.sh:/usr/local/bin/install_wordpress
        - ./docker/migratedb_import.sh:/usr/local/bin/migratedb_import
        - ./docker/postlightheadlesswpstarter.wordpress.xml:/var/www/postlightheadlesswpstarter.wordpress.xml
        - ./docker/plugins:/var/www/plugins
```

to

```
wp-headless:
    build: .
    command: bash -c 'install_wordpress && apache2-foreground'
    container_name: wp-headless
    depends_on:
        - db-headless
    env_file: ./.env
    ports:
        - '8080:8080'
    user: www-data
    volumes:
        - ./wordpress:/opt/lampp/htdocs/headless-wp
        - ./docker/install_wordpress.sh:/usr/local/bin/install_wordpress
        - ./docker/migratedb_import.sh:/usr/local/bin/migratedb_import
        - ./docker/postlightheadlesswpstarter.wordpress.xml:/var/www/postlightheadlesswpstarter.wordpress.xml
        - ./docker/plugins:/var/www/plugins
```

Even if WordPress is running, there is no JSON output, so the front-end doesn't work.

Edit: I tried installing Docker by following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30379382/revisions). I also tried extracting git to `/var/www/html` but I still get the same error:

```
/var/www/html/headless-wp-starter-master$ sudo docker-compose up -d
db-headless is up-to-date
frontend-graphql is up-to-date
frontend is up-to-date
Starting wp-headless ... error

ERROR: for wp-headless    
Cannot start service wp-headless: OCI runtime create failed:  
container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "chdir to cwd   (\"/var/www/html\") set in config.json failed: permission denied": unknown
ERROR: for wp-headless    
Cannot start service wp-headless: OCI runtime create failed:  
container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "chdir to cwd (\"/var/www/html\") set in config.json failed: permission denied": unknown  
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Link to the [full installation log](https://pastebin.com/ybYWg1bX)

Questions:

- Does this installation seem correct or have I made a mistake somewhere?
- Should I move headless-wp-starter which was downloaded from GitHub to a different folder predetermined by Docker?
- Am I installing the right version of Docker? There seem to be a lot of versions, and that's also causing confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of most bindings in `docker` and `docker-compose` is `host-item:container-item`. So when you do:

```
    volumes:
        - ./wordpress:/opt/lampp/htdocs/headless-wp
```

You are binding your local `./wordpress` to `/opt/lampp/htdocs/headless-wp` in the container but nothing points to it in the WP config files. Since the original config is creating a binding between a **relative** host directory (`./wordpress`) and the expected directory in the container, you don't need to change this.

Comment: Okay that's good at least. Any idea why it doesn't work unless I change it though?

Comment: I tried looking for the Wp-Config files but they're just not there. I've only got a the `wp-content` folder

Comment: Where is the Git project?

Comment: The git is here https://github.com/postlight/headless-wp-starter